# Selenium: Grid, Google Chrome & SSL

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, ssl-certificate

I am running a Selenium test that includes invoking two browsers: Firefox and Google Chrome. The script first invokes Firefox and all goes smoothly, but when invokes Chrome, apparently I have some problems with the SSL Certificates that does not allow the test to run.

The behavior is that I start both browsers with the following command:

sele1 = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.es/");
    //Establish the second browser
    sele2 = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*googlechrome" , "http://www.facebook.com");
    //Start the first test case
    sele1.start();
    //Start the second test case
    sele2.start();

Then after both browsers starts, all of the sudden Chrome shuts down (no error is shown).

After running all the commands needed for Firefox, the Chrome browser shows the following error on the Selenium Server (node):

Done: /status
 Couldn't proxy to http://jvutamyakw/ because host not found
 Couldn't proxy to http://lqsvihpmai/ because host not found
 Couldn't proxy to http://eqxsaiaqaf/ because host not found

I need to test both browsers, so I don't need to create another Firefox profile to test it (have tried and is not a viable solution and does not work as well).

HELP and thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you able to move to selenium2? If yes, then that would be the best way. Chrome support in selenium2 (webdriver) is far better than selenium 1

Comment: AJ, thanks for your comment! I must say that I thought I was on selenium2. To be sincere, I've been reading so much for so long and I don't know the difference. I though it was only about the server package, I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar

Comment: OK. I actually meant webdriver rather than selenium. Never mind. In your case, does the test work if you start both browsers as firefox? And are you using a selenium grid or to a standalone server?

Comment: Don't worry, since you mentioned Selenium2, I understood WebDriver and I looked up.
To answer you questions: I have tested each case in Firefox & works fine.
I have been using the selenium standalone but I have configured to have a HUB and nodes.
I know I can create a different Firefox profile (wich I have) and worked separately, but for some reason I have not be able to make it work & as I mentioned before, testing must be done in different browsers.
To tell you the truth I started installing the WebDriver but started to have problems with Maven so I decided to stop. Any help is welcome.Tx!

Comment: When you start the standalone, can you add the parameter -trustAllSSLCertificates and see if that fixes your issue?

Comment: I tried, but did not worked :(

Comment: Do you know if I can make my selenium server to go directly to a specific node... because I can have my two nodes and oblige sele2 to go straight to my port (lets say 5556) and use the custom firefox profile.
I know they go through the HUB but there is something that does not click and is not using the second HUB.
Looking for answers everywhere!

Comment: AJ, Good News! I have played both testes with trustAllSSLCertificates separately and have worked fine! (with some bumbs in the road because Facebook log in).
Now I have the way to run them in parallel...Let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time testing, I finally was able to use the *googlechrome, *firefox and *iexplore browsers with selenium on a parallel test.

Using Selenium RC I have started a Selenium Server as a HUB indicating "trustAllSSLCertificates". Then started a Selenium Server as a NODE indicating as well "trustAllSSLCertificates" and I got rid of the SSL certificate problems!

Thanks AJ!

Comment: hey, where did you specify this "trustAllSSLCertificates"?? I mean the constructor does not take addition argument then where should i specify this parameter

Comment: @Johnydep Hey, sorry it took so long to answer, but haven't login in a while. I specify the "trustAllSSLCertificates" when I started the Hub AND the Nodes. So it would be like this: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub -trustAllSSLCertificates and the same when you start the none

Comment: Awesome, this fixed the problem I was having using selenium in JavascriptMVC with some external scripts served using ssl